# Problem writing a file to /usr/local/bin from witiin a python script

Tags: python

If I run the code below in a calling directory it works as expected and returns "Successfully wrote the file Test.txt."

```
home = os.getcwd()
#os.chdir('/usr/local/bin')
OUTFILE = open('Test.txt', 'w')
today = datetime.date.today()
todayStr =(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) #string in year - month-day format)
OUTFILE.write('{0}\n'.format(todayStr))
OUTFILE.close()
if os.path.isfile('Test.txt'): #determine if Test.txt is in the cwd
    print('Successfully wrote the file Test.txt.')
else:  
    print('Failed to write the Test.txt file.')
```

but if I delete the # character from the 2nd line so that most of the code is executed from within /usr/local/bin I get the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tester.py", line 11, in <module>
    OUTFILE = open('Test.txt', 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Test.txt'
```

The permissions of the two directories appear to be the same except for the owner.  For /usr/local/bin they are

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root      4096 Apr 23 18:18 bin
```

and for the calling directory they are

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 parallels parallels    4096 Apr 24 08:35 TermTime
```

Since the permissions are the same I suspect that the issue lies with the ownerships of the directories. How can I, from within the script, temporarily modify the /usr/local/bin file to allow writing  files, then restore it to its original state?  The above code is just a snippet to test out the process.  Whatever works will become part of a script that will be distributed as an executable to people who know nothing about programming, so the solution must be transparent to the user except for being asked to provide an administrator's password.
This issue does not seem to arise when opening a file in /usr/local/bin for reading, only when opening a file for writing.

Comment: Why are you writing a text file to `/usr/local/bin` in the first place?

Comment: try running your script using `sudo python myscript.py`.

Comment: The whole point of having permissions is to keep you from doing something you shouldn't do.  If there were a way of temporarily resetting them they wouldn't be very effective, would they?

Comment: SuperStormer: So that a stand-alone executable file located in /usr/local/bin can check for the presence of a file and, if it is not there write a file with the current date.  If the file IS present it can read the file and compare the date in the file with the current date.  The point of it being a stand-alone executable is that the user need not have python on his computer and not have to do anything other than execute the file from any directory that he chooses.